# Label Features with Arcpy

Tags: python, arcgis-desktop, arcpy, labeling, contour

I had run the contour tool in my script to generate polylines.

```
Contour("rectExtract", "C:/fakepath/Class1.shp", 50,0)
```

Now I want to label the polylines with the contour-value. If I execute this script:

```
layer = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(IMXD, "")[1]
layer.showLabels=True
arcpy.RefreshActiveView()
```

it will label the polylines with the ID-Value. How can I change this?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have only one label class it's

```
layer.labelClasses[0].expression = "[<field expression here>]"
layer.showLabels = True
arcpy.RefreshActiveView()
```

Tested in ArcGIS 10.1